# Invalid vendor number specified. Try again. - App Store Connect API

Tags: api, app-store-connect

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "id": "xxxxxxx-xxxx-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyy",
            "status": "400",
            "code": "PARAMETER_ERROR.INVALID",
            "title": "A parameter has an invalid value",
            "detail": "Invalid vendor number specified. Try again.",
            "source": {
                "parameter": "filter[vendorNumber]"
            }
        }
    ]
}

  https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/salesReports

  filter[reportSubType] = OPT_IN
  filter[version] = 1_0
  filter[reportType] = SALES
  filter[frequency] = WEEKLY
  filter[reportDate] = 2018-10-07
  filter[vendorNumber] = XXXXXXXX
```

Am getting this error. In this API only with this params. Others are working fine for me. Is anyone find the Solution Please answer it.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/download_sales_and_trends_reports

Am following all steps in the documentation but i don't know what am doing wrong. :( sad

Comment: Hey were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @tkansara Not yet solved!! 

Comment: Hi, same issue here. Could you solve it @BoobeshSureshAppu?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error occurring, but I'm not sure if my solution was the same as yours. My problem was that I set the `reportType` to `SALES` and the `reportSubType` to `DETAILED`, which is not allowed as per the table at the bottom of this page:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/download_sales_and_trends_reports

This resulted in a misleading error about the vender ID, similar to what you are seeing

Comment: This solution works. tbh, the error is really misleading